# How to escape special characters in ajaxed data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I am ajaxing a page and on success I have following code:

```
success: function(html){
var product_json = [];
data=$(html);

$(".product_json", data).each(function(){
      product_json.push( jQuery.parseJSON( $(this).html() ) );
});
....
//code continue
```

My Json looks like:

```
{
  "item_logoagenzia": "/resource/loghi/medium/13.gif",
  "item_description": "Some Bernini ven.."
}
```

It works fine if I have some chars like double quotes it stopped working.

Error Json looks like:

```
 {
  "item_logoagenzia": "/resource/loghi/medium/13.gif",
  "item_description": "Some "Bernini" ven.."
}
```

I do not have control over json creation. How to modify it or remove special characters like double qoutes in script given above?

Comment: A proper JSON data service should have those quotes pre-escaped if it wants to return *valid* JSON. Where is the JSON being created? Perhaps, if you have access to the service, it would not be such a difficult change.

Comment: If the json is created by someone who couldn't spit out valid json in the first place, then it's likely impossible to programmatically make it valid json.

Comment: Your issue is the source of your JSON data not properly escaping the values.

Comment: I can not change the source of JSON data as I am its generating using Webapp layout of Adobe Business Catalyst and I am using its tag {description, 100} and if some one put wrong tag I could not check it in layout... what to do?

Comment: I suppose you could try to fix it but there will always be fringe cases that can't be fixed (e.g. if someone names their picture `", "key": "value", "key2": "`). The best you can do is to file a bug report to the service provider.

Comment: its seems we do not have a solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it. I modified my code:

```
$(".product_json", data).each(function(){
  product_json.push( jQuery.parseJSON( $(this).html() ) );
});
```

to

```
$(".product_json", data).each(function(){
var myString = $(this).html().split('"item_description":"');

var myStringDesc = myString[1]; //split the string into two

myStringDesc = myStringDesc.substring(0, myStringDesc.length - 2);

myStringDesc = escapeHtml(myStringDesc);//escapeHtml is just function for removing special chars

var myNewString = eval( '('+ myString[0]+'"item_description":"'+ myStringDesc+'"}'+')');

myNewString = JSON.stringify(myNewString);

product_json.push( jQuery.parseJSON( myNewString ) );
 });
```

I am not sure about efficiency of the code but it looks like it works fine.

Answer (score -3):

your JSON should be:

```
{
  "item_logoagenzia": "/resource/loghi/medium/13.gif",
  "item_description": "Some \"Bernini\" ven.."
}
```

EDIT: Ok, i didn't saw about the author can't edit JSON...

You can try:

```
$(this).html().replace("\"Bernini\"","\\\"Bernini\\\"")
```

But it depends, on html you receive

```
success: function(html){
var product_json = [];
data=$(html);

$(".product_json", data).each(function(){
      product_json.push( jQuery.parseJSON( $(this).html().replace("\"Bernini\"","\\\"Bernini\\\"") ) );
});
```

Another solution that might work, is that you can delete/replace all double quotes in values, except of first and last quotes....this way you will receive valid JSON string, but you will show description without a quotes or it will be with single quote.

Comment: Poster stated he does not have access over JSON creation.

Comment: The edit wasn't much of an improvement. First of all it's JSON, not HTML, and it's highly unlikely that the only time the response has misplaced quotes is when the data contains the word "Bernini".

Comment: I have tried this but no success

var product_json = [];
data=$(html);
data = data.replace(/\W/g, '');

but it says data.replace is not a method???

Comment: @Juhana it doesnt matter if it's an HTML or not, just do the replace before jQuery.parseJSON...

Comment: @AlexDn How do you decide which quotes to replace and which not? Most of the quotes are part of the JSON structure. As I said, I don't think it's *always* the word "Bernini". Your answer works for OP's example data, but *only* for the example data - nothing else.

Comment: @Juhana - from the code in the question it is html that contains JSON as element content. But yes, a solution that works only for a hard-coded value isn't really a solution.

Comment: @Juhana as i stated, it depends on HTML/String input...if it is not always Bernini, or if author not knows all possible invalid inputs, this will not work, but the author presented specific JSON string...

Comment: Deleting "all except first and last quotes" won't work because there's no way to know which quotes *should be* first or last.

Comment: ??? { "item_description": "Some "Bernini" ven.." } split by ":" then replace except last and first on second element

Comment: What if the item description is `"Greetings from "Bernini": "Capital" of the world..."`? Also, you can't know which element is the second one before you've parsed the JSON...

Comment: we talked about the value...but in your example it should be: Split by ":" then remove/replace all double quotes except first and last in "Greetings from "Bernini" and "Capital" of the world..." you will receive "Greetings from Bernini", "Capital of the world..."

Comment: But `Greetings from "Bernini": "Capital" of the world...` is supposed to be a single value (in this example).

Comment: @AlexDn Show me some code, and I'll bet you $100 that I can show you input that your code can't parse.

Comment: I agree that any code I will write, someone will able to broke it, but it possible to write code to handle the specific cases. When new problem found the code can be extended. So for authors example, it possible to write function that will fix the JSON string. Anyway the best solution is to fix service, but if it's impossible than the project shouldn't fail because of this